# Windows Batch: replace %20 to space

Tags: encoding, space

I am writing a [custom pluggable protocol handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx), which is basically the following batch script:

```
@ECHO off
SET "FullPath=%~1"
explorer.exe "%FullPath%"
```

However if Windows Explorer passes a UNC with spaces it comes to the script with %20 instead of space:

> \Groups\Group%20Micro\

instead of

> > \Groups\Group Micro\

Can you help me to figure out a batch script snippet replacing "%20" to " " or "\ " in the string please?

So far I found [Replace Percent with Bang in String](https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/2f02ec/replace_percent_with_bang_in_string/), but it requires somehow to replace % with %%, which is a separate task.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: Windows Explorer does not URLEncode filenames passed on the command line. How exactly are you getting those filenames?

Comment: I open Windows Explorer and enter XXX:\\Groups\Group Micro\ in address input field, then I push Enter and it calls the batch script, where I have XXX:\\Groups\Group%20Micro\ instead of desired XXX:\\Groups\Group Micro\.

Comment: Unfortunately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file does not contain a method to replace percent (%) characters in a string.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Using windows console shell as a CGI, utilizing SED script to URLEncode/Decode. After some time, found this as a easiest and most robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually many thanks to [Windows batch script url decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453920/windows-batch-script-url-decoding) I worked out desired snippet:

```
@ECHO off

SET "FullPath=%~1"
REM ECHO %FullPath% & PAUSE

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET FullPath=%FullPath:smb:=%
SET FullPath=%FullPath:/=\%
SET FullPath=!FullPath:%%20= !

REM ECHO %FullPath% & PAUSE

explorer.exe "%FullPath%"
```